# How to register events from within a module in Yii?

Tags: events, yii, module

I'm trying to register events from within a submodule in Yii.

It just doesn't seem to work.

The `init` method is definitely called.

```
class TestModule extends CWebModule
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->setImport(array(
            'test.models.*',
            'test.components.*',
        ));
        Yii::app()->onBeginRequest = array($this, 'onBeginRequest');
    }

    public function onBeginRequest($event) {
        die('Request!');
    }

    public function beforeControllerAction($controller, $action)
    {
        if (parent::beforeControllerAction($controller, $action))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: You try return die('Request!'); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem myself.

The problem was, that i was actually too late for onBeginRequest (Request was alrdy processed).

So what i did was writing a component with Event Handlers for onBeginRequest and onEndRequest, registering the event handlers in config/main.php and call my Module from this Component.

I basically had to proxy all these events.

Answer (score 1):

To register an event you can do:

```
$this->getEventHandlers($eventName)->add($eventHandler);
```

Where `$eventHandler` is the name of the callback you want to define for the `$eventName` event.

You can also do it with the following way:

```
$this->attachEventHandler($eventName, $eventHandler);
```

Comment: this is right for registering events but didn't solve my problem.